# C++ data containers for embedded systems

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, embedded, cortex-m

I work with embedded systems. Usually that means I have a small microcontroller with 64 - 512 KB of RAM and 128 - 1024 KB of flash memory like STM32. I prefer to use C++ for programming such systems. But I haven't still found acceptable way to deal with common data structures such as stack, queue, map, etc.

Of course, STL has all of them and many other handy things, but most STL containers require support of exceptions and dynamic memory allocation, which are usually undesirable in embedded programming.

I know we can avoid this problem by using a custom allocator, we could allocate memory from a static object pool or something similar. However the main problem I see that we can't reliably handle a case when it's not enough allocated space for inserting new element into container. STL and other stl-like libraries I've met propose only two options:

- asserts. Which means system fails when it's not enough allocated space.
- callbacks. A bit better but isn't still convenient for me.

  ```
  q.push(newElem); /* fails or just calls predefined callback
                    * when not enough space in queue.
                    */
  ```

Maybe I'm wrong. But on my opinion the best way is to have returned statuses for notifying caller that it's not enough memory for new element in a container. I would like to decide what to do with that error myself. For example, I would like to drop new element, send a message to debug log and resume normal program flow. It looks more reliable from my perspective.

In other words, I would like to have something like this:

```
queue<uint32_t, 128> q;
// some code ... 
queue::status sts = q.push(newElem);
if (sts != queue::OK)
    LOG("Not enough space in queue\r\n");

// continue normal program execution ...
```

Somebody has a suggestion how to deal with that thing?

Comment: It doesn't sound you have a problem with data containers. Rather, it sounds to me like you have a problem deciding on an error reporting strategy.

Comment: Exceptions are really the only sane way to report failures from arbitrarily nested calls, so if you cannot use exceptions, you pretty much have to make sure failures never happen. This is doable with enough effort and planning ahead. Preallocate enough memory before each operation that could fail. Use intrusive linked lists like ones in boost. For vectors and deques, reserve before adding stuff. Use move (not copy) everywhere.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I think there are many cases when just dropping new data (I mean don't push it into a container when it full) is enough, and don't need to throw an exception or return an error status further up the call stack. Anyway thank for reference to boost intrusive list. I'll try to dig there.

Comment: @n.m. sorry, my previous comment was for you.

Comment: Check out [EASTL](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL), it implements the STL slightly differently from the standard. It has the option of running without exceptions.

Comment: There's a reason why C is the dominant language in embedded systems, and it has nothing to do with conservatism.

Comment: @Lundin, everything we can do on C we can do on C++ same way. In addition C++ gives us such nice things as templates, function overload, namespaces, OOP etc. Today all of that we can get without any significant overhead. And I don't see any reason to use C not C++.

Comment: @RamanSakovich That's naive. Just disassemble the code and see what you actually get. Despite all idealists desperately believing otherwise, C++ programs give much more bloated machine code, still in the year 2017, period. Sure, you can write C++ programs as fast and compact as C programs, but _C++ programmers don't do that_. They bloat the code until meta programming hell is achieved. This is an embedded system. You cannot use exceptions. You cannot use dynamic allocation. You cannot use asserts. There is no obvious reason why you need template programming. And so on.

Comment: Btw C++ is also unsuitable for embedded systems because it cannot do type punning like C can. This makes it impossible to for example serialize data or write certain hardware drivers in C++. Things like flash/eeprom drivers, ADC drivers, timer drivers where you need to go to/from pointers to wider integer types to pointers to smaller ones, cannot be written in C++ - such code will invoke undefined behavior. While C allows you to dodge strict aliasing rules by using unions.

Comment: @Lundin, that's old and very known holy war. Let's not argue about that. The question isn't about that.

Comment: But C++ is what is causing all your problem here... or rather STL.

Comment: No. C++ doesn't have data containers without dynamic memory and exception in standard library, C doesn't have data containers in standard library at all. So, from that point of view they are equal. In any case we need to choose third party library or write it on our own. So my choice of c++ doesn't affect that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom allocator that throws std::bad_alloc when it runs out of space, then in your code wrap the section that depends on the insert succeeding in an exception handling block and deal with the allocation failure in the catch clause.

```
std::queue <message> Queue;

try
{
  Queue.insert (message {"hello world"});
}
catch (std::bad_alloc const & Error)
{
  LOG (Error.what ());
}
```

For simple scenarios this is a bit verbose, by with care (using RAII) it can be a powerful tool. In addition, if you have these simplistic scenarios allot, you can hide this pattern in a template.

```
template <typename fn>
void log_failure_and_contiue (fn Fn)
{
    try
    {
      Fn ();
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc const & Error)
    {
      LOG (Error.what ());
    }
}

std::queue <message> Queue;

log_failure_and_continue ([&] {
  Queue.insert ({ "Hello World!" });
});
```

From a performance perspective, most compilers implement zero cost exception handling, so you only take a hit if an exception is thrown, which I would think in a this case should be rare.

Comment: Exceptions cost much size in executable binary. Hundreds of KB. So, often it's not acceptable in embedded systems where flash size might be 128 KB and less.

Comment: Yes I agree, though there are ways to mitigate this. While it may be tedious, it is possible to mark the bulk of methods as `noexcept` which would allow compilers to prune much of the exception handling tables, and in the case of throwing and catching within a possibly inlined function, it can optimize out the actual exception. I don't know how well compiler optimize this type of thing right now, but it could be worth an experiment.

Comment: Another problem with exceptions in embedded systems are interrupts.

Comment: The custom allocator could call a error handler, which would log (similar to above) and then reset or just halt the system in some error state.